# Why did the majority of options of Advanced Power Options disappear?

Tags: windows-10, power, power-management

I've recently noticed that the majority of options have disappeared from the `Advanced Power Options` menu. For example, this is what it *should* look like:

[image: Expectation:]

However, this is what it looks like instead:

[image: Reality:]

Why is this? These options appear on my other laptop, but not on this one. Also, how can I restore them (without downloading any registry files)? Both of my laptops are Dell laptops.

Comment: Does changing the plan drop-down from Dell bring back those other options?

Comment: That display and setup is changing.  Look in your Power Plan dialogue and look in the left side. Options have gone there in a couple of my machines.

Comment: @gregg No, it doesn't. I've updated the screenshot with the Balanced plan instead.

Comment: @John What dialogue? I have no options on the left either. Could you please upload a screenshot?

Comment: What is this laptop? Does it support "connected standby"? Or other options that modify the power plan for "instant on" operation? If you [disable connected standby](https://www.itprotoday.com/mobile-management-and-security/disabling-windows-connected-standby) and reboot do these options come back?

Answer (score 0):

In newer Windows Updates as well as Windows Insider Updates, I have seen some settings drift into the Power Plan dialogue window as shown below. This may have happened to you.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I get the same options on the left. However, those options are present in the `Advanced Power Settings` too, such as what the power buttons do, and what closing the lid does. I am talking about where to find options such as the Processor Power Management, which I just can't seem to find anywhere.

Comment: Processor Power Management does not appear in your "Before" screenshot above. This advanced option does appear on all three of my machines (even though simple User options have changed locations).  Try resetting plan options to default, and try updating your power driver.

Comment: It occurs to me that you should call Dell Support. This is not an endemic Windows 10 problem (all my machines work just fine). If updating the Power Driver does not fix the issue, Dell may have remove the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Settings [can be hidden or displayed using Group Policy, Registry or the CMD prompt.](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/100643-remove-usb-selective-suspend-setting-power-options-windows.html) For example, to add or remove *USB selective suspend setting* from CMD:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *cmd*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and accept at the UAC dialog to get an elevated (Administrator) CMD prompt.
- Enter the following and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to show USB settings:

  powercfg -attributes 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 -ATTRIB_HIDE
- change to *+ATTRIB_HIDE* to reveal that setting.

Comment: I tried entering that command into the command prompt with no success. No new power option is available in the `Advanced Power Options` menu.